# "Where can I download music for free?" Is "for" a preposition or idiom there?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I read on newspaper. In this sentence:

> "Where can I download music for free?"

is "for" a preposition?

If "for" is a preposition, "free" couldn't be a adverb or adjective.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "for" is a preposition. Specifically, "for" is being used to indicate the items or price in a deal or transaction. For example,

> I'll give you this car for $6500.
>
> Where can I buy fruit for a low price?
>
> My friend traded me his Twix for my Reese's.

However, in a more general sense, I think that [defenition 9](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Preposition) of the word on Wiktionary also shows how "for" can be used similarly.

As for the word "free" in your sentence, it is part of the prepositional phrase "for free" which acts as an adverbial that shows *how* you are downloading the music. So, "free" is an adverb. You could even say

> Where can I download music free?

However, it sounds better if you include the preposition.

Answer (score 0):

[prepostion + adj](http://ask.yygrammar.com/app_q-28970.html)

Normally, a preposition can't link an adj / adv. But these examples may be noticed.

> Your account is far from (being) true.
>
> The ancients conceived the world as (being) flat.

So

> "Where can I download music for free?"

can be interpreted as

> "Where can I download music for **being** free?"